# CakePHP form authentication for normal requests with basic authentication for JSON

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2, basic-authentication

I'm attempting to to build a web application that can be view by a user in a browser but also has an API for developers to interface with my application. My question is how do I change the authentication based on what type of request it is in CakePHP?

I would like my application to prompt users using the site with form authentication but when a request comes in with a '.json' to use basic authentication.

I've tried this in my AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
         'loginRedirect' => array(
             'controller' => 'journeys', 
             'action' => 'index'
             ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages', 
            'action' => 'display', 'home'
            )
    ),
    'RequestHandler'
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    if($this->params['ext'] == 'json') {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');
    } else {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form');
    }
    $this->Auth->allow('display'); 
}
```

}

I have checked that the clause in the beforeFilter if works and it does but I seem to get redirected to my form authentication no matter what URL I try and access in my application

The login function in my UsersController file looks like:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
}
```

I have read the docs on the CakePHP website but I can't seem to find an example that will help me. Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED FOR CORRECTION TO CODE AND MORE INFORMATION

I have carried on looking at this problem and Ive noticed that if I log the value of:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate
```

in the beforeFilter it says that it is basic but it's still sending me to the form log in.

Comment: Do you realise that the condition that checks the extension isn't doing anything, because it's setting the same authentication type each time? Also, which version of CakePHP are you using? 2.x I'm guessing, but 2.0.x or 2.1.x?

Comment: The reason it is setting the same type every time is because I think CakePHP defaults to form, so all I'm doing is specifying something different for the cases where the address has a JSON extension. I'm using Cake 2.2.3.

Comment: @JonathanCairns Actually you're right about that piece of code and I've fixed it but it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: I came across this question when looking for a solution to this problem and it turns out that your question is actually the answer! I don't know why it isn't working for you, but as soon as I used what you have in your beforeFilter (minus the $this->Auth->allow('display'); ) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Excerp from the docs (see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html):

> Because basic and digest authentication don’t require an initial POST
>   or a form so if using only basic / digest authenticators **you don’t
>   require a login action in your controller**. Also you can set
>   AuthComponent::$sessionKey to false to ensure AuthComponent doesn’t
>   try to read user info from session.

So you do not require a login action. You could check for the authentication method in your users controller and skip the login action if the authentication method is "Basic".